# Swift - Bar Button Item support function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a Bar Button Item in the navigation bar of the view (Edit Button). Unlike other buttons (UIButton), I am unable to press ctrl and drag to view controller to create a function to handle it. I want when the button is pressed, a function body to execute.

How can I link them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show the **assistant editor**

[image]

and use the **document outline** (the left bar that list all your view controllers and relative items) for select the bar button item, then CTRL & drag or drag with your right mouse button:

[image]

Automatically for bar button item Xcode link as action:

[image]

Comment: I actually didn't try from the side nav to drag and drop. Thanks it worked!

Comment: you're welcome! When you have problem or you want to be sure for what item you've selected in view controllers use the document outline ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button is selected (The view should darken a bit everywhere expect where the button is) and open up the Utilities area. Open the Connections inspector in utilities (an arrow pointing to the right) and under Triggered Segues drag from the circle to your code and create your action.